# Parse Ascii Escaped String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ascii

Say we're given a string that itself contains ASCII escape characters, such as `"\x64"` (note that this is the contents of the string, not what it would be in code). Is there an easy way in JavaScript to parse this to its actual character?

There's the old trick of using `JSON.parse` but that seems to only work with unicode escape sequences and can't recognize ASCII ones, as in:

```
JSON.parse(`"\\u0064"`); // Output: "d" (as expected)
JSON.parse(`"\\x64"`);   // ERROR: Unexpected token x
```

Is there an equivalent that would work for the ASCII escape sequence? I know that using `eval()` works but I'd really rather not use `eval`.

EDIT: To clarify, some characters in the original string may not be escaped; as we may need to parse `"Hello Worl\x64"`, for instance.

Comment: JSON specs do not have any ASCII escape characters only unicode. https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to replace all the `\x**` patterns in the string, using a callback to parse them as base 16 integers and pass the result to [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to convert to a character:

```js
const str = "\\x48\\x65ll\\x6f\\x20W\\x6f\\x72\\x6c\\x64";
const res = str.replace(/\\x(..)|./g, (m, p1) => p1 ? String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16)) : m);
console.log(res);
```

If you don't mind overwriting the original string, this can be simplified slightly to:

```js
let str = "\\x48\\x65ll\\x6f\\x20W\\x6f\\x72\\x6c\\x64";
str = str.replace(/\\x(..)/g, (m, p1) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16)));
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I'm just astonished that functionality like this isn't built into the language and requires us to manually pick apart the string, especially since JavaScript's own interpreter does support ascii escaped characters. Still, thanks for your help.

Comment: @mt_xing yeah - also you'd think that JSON.parse might be able to deal with both formats. Anyway... I'm glad this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function to evaluate a string in the same way it would be evaluated from Javascript source code, you'll only need to make sure you quote its content as such:

```
eval("\"\\x64\"") // will return the javascript string: "d"
```